# Правила mod_rewrite для web.config IIS

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать правила `mod_rewrite` для web.config IIS?

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|uploads/.*|favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|captcha/.*|application/modules/.*/templates|templates|js|robots\.txt|application/controllers/install/images/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собрал web.config с помощью IIS manager 7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|user_guide|uploads/.*|favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|captcha/.*|application/modules/.*/templates|templates|js|robots\.txt|application/controllers/install/images/.*)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```